# A measurable function from a product space depend only on a countable number of coordinates

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following question from exercise 59 or 2.4.1 (4) in Terence Tao's notes on measure theory.

Let $((X_{\alpha},\mathfrak{B_{\alpha}}))_{\alpha \in A}$ be a familiy of measurable spaces and define the product $\sigma$-algebra on $X_A$ to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that all the coordinate functions are measurable.

**I want to show that**

*If $f:\ X_a\ \to\ [0,\infty]$ is $\mathfrak{B}_A$-measurable then there exists an at most countable set $B\subset A$ and a $\mathfrak{B}_B$-measurable function $f_B:\ X_B \ \to \ [0,\infty]$ such that $f=f_B \circ\pi_B$*

I can do the following:

If we for $B\subset A$ denote with $\mathcal{Z}_B\subset \mathfrak{B}_A$ the set of all $\pi_B^{-1}(E_B),\ E_B \in \mathfrak{B}_B$ we have (from the exercise 2.4.1 (3) done before) that for any $E_A \in \mathfrak{B}_A$ that there exists some countable $B\subset A$ such that  $E_A \in \mathcal{Z}_B$.

Finding such a countable $B_i$ for each $F_i \subset [0,\infty]$ in some countable generator of $\mathcal{B}([0,\infty])$ and letting $J=\cup B_i$ we get that $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{Z}_J$ (Where $J$ of course is countable) From this we get the sense in whihch $f$ only depends on a countable number of coordinates.

Now I would believe that $f=\left.f\right|_{X_J} \circ \pi_J $, and I know that $f=\left.f\right|_{X_J}$ is $\mathcal{Z}_B$-measurable. **But I'm unsure of how to prove the equality of these two functions**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path, but there is an issue in how you implemented it. Note that $X_J\times X_{A\setminus J}$ can be identified in a natural way with $X_A$. It follows that $X_J$ is a factor of $X_A$ and not a subset; in particular, the restriction $\left.f\right|_{X_J}$ is not well-defined.

In order to define the function $f_J$ so that $f=f_J\circ\pi_J$, pick any $y\in X_{A\setminus J}$ and define $f_J$ by $f_J(x)=f(x_J,y_{A\setminus J})$, where we identify $X_A$ with $X_J\times X_{A\setminus J}$.

Let's verify that $f=f_J\circ\pi_J$, which amounts to showing that $f(x_J,x_{A\setminus J})=f(x_J,y_{A\setminus J})$. Suppose not, then there exists a measurable set $F\subseteq [0,\infty]$ that contains $f(x_J,x_{A\setminus J})$ but not $f(x_J,y_{A\setminus J})$. But then $f^{-1}(F)$ would not be in $\mathcal{Z}_J$. A similar argument shows also that $f_J$ is $\mathcal{Z}_J$-measurable.